# Eclipse CDT C/C++ coding style

Tags: coding-style, eclipse-cdt, code-formatting

I would like to force the following coding style option in Eclipse CDT.

in each if statement, even a single statement should be in a block of code.
for instance:

```
if (1 == 1) nop();
```

will become

```
if (1 == 1)
  {
    nop();
  }
```

Is there a to force it, because this specific option is not part of the coding-style configuration of eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an astyle plugin for eclipse. Install it and you can adjust every option you will ever whish including the one you mentioned
astyleclipse.sourceforge.net/